# why does first example constructor set `__index` on `self`?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am just starting to look at Lua, and I'm looking at the [introductory Lua example for "classes"](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html).

```
Account = {balance = 0}

function Account:new (o)
  o = o or {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end
```

I do not understand why the constructor is not just

```
function Account:new (o)
  o = o or {}
  setmetatable(o, {__index = self})
  return o
end
```

I would appreciate any help in understanding this.

**Edit:**

@Egor observes that the 2nd approach would create too many metatables. OK, I get that (and indeed, it shd have been obvious). But it the first method still feels odd (e.g., it repeatedly sets `__index` on `Account`). Maybe something like this would meet both objections?

```
Account = {balance = 0}
Account_meta = {__index = Account}

function Account:new (o)
  o = o or {}
  setmetatable(o, Account_meta)
  return o
end
```

Comment: In the second example you're creating new metatable for each object.  It's too memory consuming.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks. Might you comment on my edit?

Comment: The metatable might be the same table as the class itself, this would save one more table.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Sure. But assume that I am not working on a system where every byte of memory matters; is there any other reason not to use the 3rd approach? Thanks!

Comment: 3rd approach is absolutely OK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only reason for this approach is to tie it with inheritance in the [next section](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html).

The inheritance implementation there creates the prototype for `SpecialAccount`s with `SpecialAccount = Account:new()`, and new instances of `SpecialAccount` are then created with `instance = SpecialAccount:new()`.

If we want exactly this approach to work one of these two calls has to set `SpecialAccount.__index` to `SpecialAccount`. And assuming we want `__index` to only be set on the prototypes/metatabless/classes, it has to be the second one. This costs us one assignment repeated during each object creation, but I guess this was not considered significant for the sake of an example.